Link DB Oracle11g to Oracle19c
Question?
is there a way or possible way to Connect Oracle11g and Oracle19c Database
the Scenario is Oracle11g Table1 transfer specific Columns of data to Oracle19c Table2
same column structure for both tables.
for Example:
FROM
Oracle11g
PRODUCT



Product_name
product_description




Bolt
Metal


Ziptie
Plastic



SUPPLIER



Product_name
Supplier




Bolt
Home Depot


Ziptie
Plastic



TO
Oracle19c
PRODUCT WAREHOUSE



Product_name
product_description
Supplier




Bolt
metal
Home Depot


Ziptie
plastic
Home Depot



